# HAproxy: Tomcat and OutOfMemory

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat7, haproxy

With a Linux Ubuntu, Java 7, Tomcat 7 I have a problem when using OutOfMemory HAproxy

The original configuration has no problems (and has been active for many days): frontend Apache Tomcat and two nodes where you installed a web application that exposes Web services SOAP.

Instead when enabled HAProxy after about 24/36 hours nodes have a problem OutOfMemory.
Using a professional tool, there were no problems Leak, but simple OutOfMemory. Even by increasing the RAM of a 25% continues to be the problem OutOfMemory.

Do you know any problem in this configuration? It could be the check GET web services enabled in HAProxy that create problems?
Any idea?

Comment: So why do you think it's haproxy that is responsible for it?

Comment: Because with HAproxy (and same configuration Linux, Java, Tomcat, WebApp...) I have always a OutOfMemory.

Comment: But does it consume a lot of memory?

Comment: The RAM has been increased with HAProxy. The heap usage increases a little at a time and then after 24/36 hours there is OutOfMemory. I also used plumbr, but does not report problems leak

Comment: Does it haproxy that consumes a lot of memory? "The RAM has been increased with HAProxy" --- this is not a technical proof, sorry. For me the moderately loaded haproxy process does not consume more than 20Mb.